# Create a sequence number that will change per year only

Tags: php

Need some help.
I need to create a sequence number which will change per year only.
For example,this year is 2017.The sequence number will be 0000001.
If the year will be 2018, sequence number will change to 0000002.

How to make it possible?
I've tried to create script using php but i failed to create the said function.

Here is my code:

```
$year= '2017';
$n=0;
$n = str_pad($n + 1, 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
if($year==2017){
  $number=$n;
}else{
  $number = $n+1;
}
echo $number;
```

Anyone can help?
Thanks

Comment: Are you hard coding 2017. Or is there any other logic behind?

Comment: There is a logic...getting the current year in PHP. date('Y')

Comment: Oh ok. So the sequence number starts from 2017

Comment: Yes it will start this year

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$year = '2017';
$seq = sprintf('%07d', $year - 2016);

echo $seq;
```

Comment: whats this 07 again?

Comment: @CaspainCaldion I've been reading the documentation too. I was confused. I don't know, but I assume it is saying "7 characters long and use 0 as padding". So the subtraction is padded by x 0, where x is 7 - length of $year - 2016

Comment: @JustCarty Correct.